# Handling Shift-Enter event in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want a textbox where the user can shift-enter or ctrl-enter to add a newline without submitting.  I found the following post on how to do ctrl-enter

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/67ef5912-aaf7-43cc-bfb0-88acdc37f09c

works great! so i added my own block to capture shift enter like so:

```
  else if (((keyData & swf.Keys.Shift) == swf.Keys.Shift) && ((keyData & swf.Keys.Enter) == swf.Keys.Enter) && Keyboard.FocusedElement == txtMessage)
  {
     // SHIFT ENTER PRESSED!
  }
```

except now the box is capturing other shift combinations such as the question mark and squiggly braces and then adding a newline.  What do I need to change to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Julien, a TextBox captures {} and ? by default anyway. Are you inferring that your code block captures those keys too?

Comment: My code is adding a newline when I write a question mark or squiggly brace.  Sorry if that wasn't clear, I only want shift-enter and ctrl-enter to write newlines.

Comment: You should be careful with the ctrl-enter. I am pretty sure that the agreed upon action for that key-combination is "submit".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't mix with WinForms. Try:

```
<TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
```

with this event handler:

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Control + Enter pressed");
        }
        else if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Shift + Enter pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe something like this didn't pop up from my googling.

Answer (score 14):

I prefeer use keybinnding inputs:

```
 <TextBox>
      <TextBox.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Key="ENTER" Modifiers="Shift" Command="{Binding YoutCommand}"/>
      </TextBox.InputBindings>
 </TextBox>
```

Comment: I agree with you. Go for XAML when it is that easy =)

Answer (score 3):

After trying most things i decided to experiment a little my self. And this seems to do the job in an easy

In the designer view. Select the textbox and under the "events" lightningbolt doublecklick on key->KeyDown. you will be placed in the code.

paste this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Shift)
            {
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("shift enter");
                }
            }
        }
```

If the key shift is pressed. and then in that if-statement. if Enter is pressed a messagebox will pop up.

Swap the messagebox with your task.

Answer (score 1):

e.Shift already works with KeyDown but beware the order. A Shift or Ctrl modifier must be checked first. If you check `Enter` before `Shift + Enter`,  Shift will never be caught.  Else is also important to prevent double processing.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) {
        // check this first
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)  {
        // don't put this on top
    }
}
```